# Is there a simple way to use PySpark DataFrame filter() to split a frame into exactly two frames, based on condition?

Tags: filter, pyspark, aws-glue

I'm working on a data warehouse project.  I'm reading input data into a frame, and then I want to filter out the bad rows.  However, I want to print some sample bad rows. What I have now is

```
df_good = df_input.filter(((df_input.info.isNull()) | (df_input.info == '')))
```

This filter works, but I cannot print out a sample of the dropped records.  What I would like is something like:

```
df_keep, df_reject = df_input.filter_split(((df_input.info.isNull()) | (df_input.info == '')))
print("Sample rejected records:")
df_reject.show(5)
```

I found one method which involves running the filter, then joining the good data back to the original data with an outer join, then filtering to find original data not-in the good data set.  But this iterates over the original data twice; I would like to pass through the list just once.

Any ideas?  I am doing this in AWS Glue, so I may be able to use a Dynamic Frame function.

Comment: Why not define the condition and negate it? First `good = ((df_input.info.isNull()) | (df_input.info == ''))` then do `df_keep, df_reject = df_input.filter(good), df_input.filter(~good)`

Comment: Negating the filter is clean, but it still requires operations on the frame.  It would be better to have one operation that splits the frame into rows that pass or fail the filter.